# How to redirect to already opened port using Ip tables

Tags: iptables, envoyproxy

I am using envoy proxy(8001).
Current Situation : when I curl localhost:8001, envoy will inject some data in packets and send the result to remoteip:32100

What i want is like
Expectation: when I curl remoteip:32100 it should redirect through localhost:8001 and inject some data from envoy then send the result to remoteip:32100
I tried the below rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d remoteip -m tcp --dport 32100-j REDIRECT --to-ports 8001
```

The packet is redirected to 8001, but I am getting envoy errors when trying this.
Please help

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the "envoy errors"?

Comment: I have updated the question with images. I am using envoy sds so that the envoy will convert http to mtls . This is working if --dport is configured as any value other than 32100.

https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/security/secret

Comment: Your qiestion about envoy not about iptables problems. Redirect itself is succseful.